# How to delete particular columns data in database using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hi iam trying to delete certain columns data from database.Here is my code for delete query.

```
//getting column id by comparing the id need to delete the data from that row.
$id=$_GET['id'];
$res = "DELETE rental_annual_rent,
rental_block,
rental_street,
rental_area,
rental_town,
rental_state,
rental_pincode
 FROM house_details 
 WHERE house_details_id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($res);
if(mysql_affected_rows()){
    echo "successfully deleted";
    session_start();
    header("Location:property.php");
    }else{
    echo "Failure";
    }
```

First iam inserting house_details data into database but i need to delete only particular data from that columns

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: `$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);` just delete that. You're probably looking for `mysql_affected_rows()` once you use DELETE correctly.

Comment: *Hold on there cowboy*, that isn't how DELETE is used http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html unless you want to delete multiple tables. `DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]` and `mysql_fetch_array()` is for SELECT, ***not*** DELETE.

Comment: Create table y as select a, b, c from x; drop table x;

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have replaced with mysql_affected_rows but it is not working

Comment: reload my comment above. I made a few edits to it. and unsure what it is you want to do here exactly.

Comment: You cannot "delete" specific columns within a row.  You can update the row and set the column values to `NULL` or an empty string `""`, but you do that with an `UPDATE` statement, not a `DELETE` statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- first iam inserting details of property and rental details into house_details table but i need to delete rental_details columns data from house_Details.

Comment: @PatrickQ as i tried with update query also it is not working can anyone update it

Comment: `DELETE FROM house_details WHERE house_details_id='$id'` - That's how and will delete every row associated with `$id`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if i do that it will delete entire row but i dont want to delete entire row only some columns i need to delete

Comment: see the answer given below. You can't use DELETE like that, as I already mentioned here in comments.

Comment: may be  the answer can give you other clarification too what you want to change. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is an `UPDATE`, not a `DELETE` since you want to keep the row, but just clear/blank/unset certain columns within the row.

```
$res = "UPDATE house_details SET
    rental_annual_rent = NULL,
    rental_block = NULL,
    rental_street = NULL,
    rental_area = NULL,
    rental_town = NULL,
    rental_state = NULL,
    rental_pincode = NULL
 WHERE house_details_id='$id'";
```

Note that you should really be sanitizing your `id` input before using it in the query, you should parameterize it, and you should also migrate from the `mysql` library to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @thank you i have changed my code thanks for the idea